# HTML Nested Element

Tags: html, nested, element

What HTML elements can have other HTML elements nested? For suppose, a **p** cannot be having nested elements. Is there a list W3C standards where I can see whether an element can have nested elements?

Thanks

Comment: Thanks. But its not only about p. My question is about all elements where they can have any other nested. For e.g. Can I have an anchor tag inside a ul->li or div inside list? Is there any specifications/practice on dos and donts?

Comment: Have a look at the link before you reply. It refers to http://w3c.github.io/ There you can find what you need.

Comment: Apologies for being naive. I have visited the link already. Its too technical. First time I heard 'phrasing content'. I am looking into the w3c, still lot of technical words used.